# Newbie : How do I begin my journey?

Tags: trailhead, developer

I am a novice and I really want to be a Salesforce developer.

What do I do?
Are there prequesites?
Where do I begin on trailhead?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. This community is here to answer questions around specific problems and generally does not cover questions likely to be opinionated. I recommend you raise this question on the salesforce trailblazer communities.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a computer, access to the Internet, and the time, you can become a Salesforce developer. I would definitely recommend that you start with the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) modules. Different people will likely suggest different things, but I'll give you the same advice that I give everyone who decides they want to become a developer.

First, learn how to use Salesforce as a user, go through the trails about creating cases, opportunities, leads, campaigns, the basic stuff you'd want to know about using the system. Then, go through the System Administrator trails to learn about how to configure Salesforce. You'll spend a lot of time doing this as a developer. Finally, you can start on the Developer trails. In all, this is probably 80-120 hours of active learning.

I also suggest that you take a quick course *elsewhere* that's not on Salesforce about learning how computers work, something titled "Introduction to Programming Logic" or "Programming Logic 101." You will want to understand the basics of how computers work, such as the heap and stack, static versus dynamic memory, flow control and branching, variables, and so on. You'll also want to have a basic understanding of object-oriented programming, including classes and interfaces.

In other words, learning programming logic should be considered a prerequisite before starting on Apex/Lightning Web Components, etc. Salesforce's trailheads and documentation assumes you already have some idea of what programming is, so it doesn't go over the basics. You'll write better code if you take the time to do this. I don't have any specific book/tutorial/youtube recommendations, but a few Internet searches should give you lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

The [Set Up Your Workspace and Install Developer Tools](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/set-up-your-workspace-and-install-developer-tools) and [Developer Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) trails are probably the place to start.

As far as prerequisites, trailhead does assume that you have some knowledge of programming (more specifically, Object-Oriented Programming). You'd probably be able to fumble through the modules in those trails without background programming knowledge, given enough time and determination, but knowing even a little bit of programming will help massively (and help you in asking for more specific help on sites like this one).

Trailhead isn't going to contain much in the way of OOP fundamentals though. If you need to learn about or brush up on OOP, then you'll want to find a resource (not trailhead) specifically dedicated to that. Apex, Salesforce's proprietary language, is based off of Java, so an introductory resource on Java may be a good choice. I'm afraid I have no suggestions for finding that resource.